# Error Handler for Looped Excel Workbook Scraper

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am working on code to scrape multiple workbooks for a single cell value and import that value into a master spreadsheet. The code that I have below works great when it works, but I have found that there are a couple of workbooks that may have issues due to being locked down or some other issue that is resulting in an error which stops the code. What I would like to do is use the `On error resume next` command to continue importing values from the other workbooks, but I need a way to log the workbooks that have been skipped due to an error so that the values can be manually pulled (ideally on a separate worksheet in the master workbook). Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub CopyRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wkbDest As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long

Const strPath As String = "E:\Desktop\Example\"
    ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
    On Error Resume Next
       'locate last row to start copying new value from the next spreadsheet
        LastRow = wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'From the Basis & Credits cell AB46, copy to last row+1 in the Master sheet starting in row A2
        .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB46").Copy
         wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here you can define a new function that helps you to track error

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    'you need to create this worksheet named "Log"
    Dim LogSheet As Worksheet
    Set LogSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
    'clear contents in log sheet
    LogSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
    
    Const strPath As String = "E:\Desktop\Example\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        path = strPath & strExtension
        If VerifyTasks(strPath & strExtension, wkbDest) Then
            LogSheet.Range("A" & LogSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strPath & strExtension & "  " & "succeeded"
        Else
            LogSheet.Range("A" & LogSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strPath & strExtension & "  " & "Failed"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function VerifyTasks(path As String, ByRef wkbDest As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errorhandler:
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(path)
    With wkbSource
       'locate last row to start copying new value from the next spreadsheet
        LastRow = wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'From the Basis & Credits cell AB46, copy to last row+1 in the Master sheet starting in row A2
        .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB46").Copy
         wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    VerifyTasks = True
    Call closeWorkbook(wkbSource)
    Exit Function
errorhandler:
    Call closeWorkbook(wkbSource)
    VerifyTasks = False
End Function

Sub closeWorkbook(ByRef xWb As Workbook)
    If Not xWb Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xWb.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a `Loop Without Do` compile error that doesn't make sense to me. I see that the `Do While` function is listed, so I don't know what's happening. Thoughts?

Comment: Never mind, I think there was an `End With` missing.

Comment: I can get through the first subroutine but when the error handler function is triggered I get a compile error that says `Label not defined`

Comment: The with the line is a mistake just remove it in the main sub (I have edited the code). I added on error goto 0 to reset error condition. if you get the error it means your error occurs in some other place. take a try and share the result.

Comment: That works great, thank you! I did have to change the `End Function` to `Exit Function` before the errorhandler to resolve the compile error, but the rest of the code works great. Is there a way to get a log of the failed workbooks or will I just have to notate which ones failed as is loops through the directory?

Comment: I did not get the question, but you could Debug.print (full path) of each workbook that has an issue, or creates a separate sheet (log), and keeps track of the state of each workbook.

Comment: I would like to create a separate sheet for a log. How would I do that?

Comment: Please add a new worksheet named "Log" and use the code that I edited. and apply the this answer if it solved your problem. thanks

Comment: Shahin Rahimmi, you're my savior! This works exactly how I wanted it to, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey, so when I run this code on a small batch of files, it works great. However, when I try to run it on the 289 workbooks that I need to sort through, all of the failed files open in the background and the main workbook ends up freezing which negates all of the work. Is there a way to suppress all messages and not open the workbooks that fail in the background? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217842/discussion-between-josephd-and-shahin-rahimi).

Answer (score 0):

`On Error Resume Next` does resume execution with the next line of code, basically "hiding" that an error has occurred, so you'll have no chance of logging.

What you probably want is `On Error GoTo [Label]`. At the label, you can call an error logging routine. If there is no error, you skip the error handler.

```
Do While condition
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  
  ' Do Stuff

  GoTo NoError
  ErrorHandler:

  ' Log error

  NoError:
Loop
```

As you can see, the flow is already a bit confusing, as very often with `GoTo` in VBA. It is basically the equivalent of a hypothetical `Try Catch` though:

```
Do While condition
  Try
    ' Do Stuff
  Catch
    ' Log error
  End Try
Loop
```

As with exceptions, it's usually better to explicitly check for conditions you "expect" to be plausible that might cause an error, and use such error handler constructs sparingly where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the information LWChris. I am very new to constructing an error handler and don't really know where to start. I understand what you're saying about using the `On Error GoTo [Label]` function instead of `On Error Resume Next`, but I don't know how to construct the error handler to log the filename of the workbook that had an error and where to easily view that. Any thoughts?